# LocalStorage Challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have already gone through reading posts as much as i could and got most of this working, except the last part. I am trying to have a set of events from a calendar stored in localStorage, then need to be able to retrieve them via the button 'Saved Events'. Right now the button only retrieves one event and I need to get any and all events in the storage. I also made a fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1dcps6q/2/).

Any help or feedback would be appreciated, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <style>
 .eventer { 
    background-color:#9CB2B7; 
    padding: 15px; width: 150px; 
    height: auto; margin:0; color: #fff; 
    letter-spacing:0.7px;
 }
 .selctor {
    background-color: #A0AABA;
     width: 180px;
 }
 a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.7px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px;
  }
 #result{ height:200px; outline:dotted 2px red; padding-bottom:150px; }
 </style>
 </head>
<body>
<div>
     <div class="eventer" rel="0"><strong>Event 1 Saturday</strong><br />
     yakedi yak</div>
     <p class="selctor" rel="0"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
  </div>
  <br /><br />

<div>
     <div class="eventer" rel="1"><strong>Event 1 Saturday</strong><br />
     more yakedi yak</div>
     <p class="selctor" rel="1"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
  </div>
  <br /><br />

<div>
     <div class="eventer" rel="2"><strong>Event 3 Sunday</strong>
     <p>new yakedi yak</p></div>
     <p class="selctor" rel="2"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
  </div>
  <br /><br />

<div>
     <div class="eventer" rel="3"><strong>Event 4 Sunday</strong>
     <p>blah blah dooodah</p></div>
     <p class="selctor" rel="3"><a href="#">Add to Schedule</a></p>
  </div>
  <br />

  <input type="submit" id="buttn" value="Saved Events"><br /><br />

    <div>Selected Events are:<br />
    <div id="result">
     </div>      
      </div>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".selctor").click(function () {
        var i=$(this).attr("rel");
        console.log(i);
        var eventsArray=document.getElementsByClassName("eventer");
        eventSelctd=(eventsArray[i]).outerHTML;
        console.log("selected event is" + " " + eventSelctd);

        if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
             localStorage.setItem("schedule "+ i, eventSelctd);
        }
            else {
             document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
            }

});
    $("#buttn").click(function () {
    var storaged = localStorage.length;

    for( var i=0; i<storaged; i++ )
    {
    console.log("Your stored events are " + localStorage[i]);
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    $("#result").html(key + value);
    //$("#result").html(localStorage[i]);
    }
    //console.log("stored schedule is " + allEventers);
    });

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say you made a fiddle? ... Any chance we might get to see that?

Comment: hi Robert, i thought I made a link, it must've stripped the html, here it is: <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/s1dcps6q/2/" style="target:_blank">   thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like there were some problems with the way you were accessing localStorage.

localStorage is an object, not an array, so you have to access it differently. Have a look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s1dcps6q/3/

And the updated JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".selctor").click(function() {
        var i = $(this).attr("rel");
        var eventsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("eventer");
        eventSelctd = (eventsArray[i]).outerHTML;

        if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("schedule " + i, eventSelctd);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
        }

    });
    $("#buttn").click(function() {

        //var allEventers;
        var storaged = Object.keys(localStorage).length; // count the number of properties of the object

        for (var i = 0; i < storaged; i++) {
            $("#result").append(localStorage["schedule " + i]); // add to the div, not replace the content
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: after more testing I see what it is doing. Data is stored in localStorage just fine, the recall button only recalls data that is consecutive. Because it is sorting according to "rel" it ignores rels that are out of the sequence. lets say rel 1,2,4 are stored in storage, the button only calls back 1 and 2. Any fix or suggestions would be appreciated as I need to ge this done for work.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s1dcps6q/4/

here is the code, this does what I wanted it to and wanted to share with anyone who comes across this challenge. I made modifications to swatkins code above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".selctor").click(function () {
        var i=$(this).attr("rel");
        console.log(i);
        var eventsArray=document.getElementsByClassName("eventer");
        eventSelctd=(eventsArray[i]).outerHTML;
        console.log("selected event is" + " " + eventSelctd);

        if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
             localStorage.setItem("schedule "+ i, eventSelctd);
             //console.log("local Storage should read " + eventSelctd);
        }
            else {
             document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
            }

});
    $("#buttn").click(function () {
    var storaged = Object.keys(localStorage).length;
    console.log("test: " + storaged);

    for( var i=0; i<storageLength; i++ )
    {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    $("#result").append(value);
    }
    });
    $("#buttn2").click(function(){
    localStorage.clear();
    $("#result").html('');
    console.log("Storage is cleared");
    });
});
```